# mysql: import large number of rows from client to server

Tags: mysql, import, dump

I have an application that generates potentially huge tables, various clients should be able to send data to a central database.
Right now I'm thinking about batching the requests and sending them via php, which is probably the classic approach.
I was wondering, is there a precise reason why I should not let the application dump the table, upload the dump to the server via post and let the server import again the table?
I'm concerned with security since the server is reachable from internet, can you slip malicious code into a sql dump? if so, can you sanitize the dump before import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data import can't modify code, but malicious *data* can be included in the data import.

Then your application might use data in a way that risks it becoming code. There are two common paths:

**Secondary SQL injection.** You query some data, and interpolate the results into another string which is then run as a query or else as a command.

Solution: filter all untrusted input either with SQL query parameters, or whitelisting.

**Cross-site scripting (XSS).** You query some data and output it in a web page. If the data contains an inline Javascript expression, it can cause the browser of the user to run Javascript code unintentionally, capture data from their browser, and do something malicious with that data.

Solution: filter all untrusted output with a function like htmlentities(), which defeats XSS by escaping `<script>` tags.

You asked if there's some way to sanitize the dump before import. **Maybe.** But it's more likely that doing this would restrict your import data too much. Maybe the data legitimately needs to contain apostrophes and `<` characters.

It's usually better to let the data be imported as is, but then be careful about how you use the data subsequently, as I described above.

Comment: In the first case how would I filter the input? if the client sends the dump to the server then the mysql instance on the server will have to import the dump directly, without php.

Comment: Don't filter the input when you load. Filter subsequent use of the data, *if* you use it in a SQL query.

Comment: Ok, in your experience, is this approach really doable? I mean in all my searches everyone insisted on optimizing the queries, but I have never found anyone suggesting a dump. I'm just wondering if I'm doing something idiotic in some way.
In any case, my tables are quite simple, I can filter data before import without any concern, what is the best way to do that when importing from a dump?

Comment: I use filtering or query parameters every time I use data in an SQL statement. I use htmlentities() every time I output data to a web page. This is the right way to do it.